# Function calling for each element in a list

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

Using only recursion (ie. no loops of any sort), given a list of elements, how can I call a function each time for every element of the list using that element as an argument each time in OCaml? Fold and map would not work because although they are applying a function to each element, it returns a list of whatever function I called on each element, which is not what I want.

To better illustrate what I'm essentially trying to do in OCaml, here's the idea of what I want in Ruby code:

```
arr.each {|x| some_function x}
```

but I must do this using only recursion and no iter functions

Comment: Are you simply asking for [List.iter](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#6_Iterators) or am I missing something ?

Comment: @Sensucht: He's probably being asked to implement `List.iter` himself.

Comment: Fold does *not* return a list. You could use `List.fold_left`, if you did not have a requirement to roll your own recursion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct recursive function is described as:

- if the list is empty, do nothing;
- else, process the first element and then the tail of the list.

The corresponding code is:

```
let rec do_all f lst =
match lst with
| [] -> ()
| x :: xs -> f x; do_all f xs
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly general template for a recursive function would be this:

```
let rec f x =
    if x is trival to handle then
        handle x
    else
        let (part, rest) = division of x into smaller parts in
        let part_result = handle_part part in
        let recursive_result = f rest in
        combine part_result recursive_result
```

Since you don't need a result, you can skip a lot of this.

Which parts of this template seem most difficult to do for your problem?

**Update**

(As @EduardoLeón points out, when working with lists you can test for a trivial list *and* break down the list into smaller parts using pattern matching. Pattern matching is cool.)

**Update 2**

My question is sincere. Which part are you having trouble with? Otherwise we don't know what to suggest.

Comment: Please don't tell newbies to use `if-then-else` when pattern matching will do.

Comment: It's hard to write a pattern match for a generalized problem, though. I don't want to write code, just lay out some ideas.

Comment: Lists in OCaml are a very specific data type that can be pattern matched against.

Comment: I know that very well. But I don't want to write code for the person.

Comment: @EduardoLeón Lists in Ocaml are the typical recursively defined  data type that is THE basic data structure for every FP language - nothing specific.